# URL Polyfill for IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

**I am creating a URL in my angular app using new URL as below. This works on all browsers except IE11.**

So I tried to add "url-polyfill" to my "package.json" and used import 'url-polyfill'  in polyfills.ts file.

But still i am getting object doesn't support action error for this line in IE11. Can anyone provide some thoughts on what i am doing wrong here.

```
 url = new URL(url).pathname.toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Angular includes imports to core-js@3 (you don't need to install something), so try these polyfills instead:

```
import 'core-js/features/url';
import 'core-js/features/url-search-params';
```

Comment: thank you. Mine is an exisiting application and core-js 2.7.4 is being used as of now. If i update it to 3.0 then i see error cannot resolve core-js/es6/array in "/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js"

This is because 3.0 doesn't have separate folders for es6 and es7.

Comment: thank you this worked and i resolved the core-js error by adding the paths in tsconfig.json.